# Can I automate `gcloud auth login`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

I am unable to non-interactively activate my Google Cloud service account; even after reading several SO threads.

1. Creating a service account

`gcloud iam service-accounts create my-awesome-acct ...`

2. Creating a role for the service account

`gcloud iam roles create AwesomeRole \
--permissions storage.objects.create,storage.objects.delete ....`

3. Generating the keys

`gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/awesome-key.json ...`

4. Activating the service account

`gcloud auth activate-service-account my-awesome-acct ~/awesome-key.json`

**My Issue**

Even after following the above steps, when I run `gsutil ...` commands, I still get the error message:

```
$ gsutil cp my_file.tgz gs://my_bucket

  Copying file://my_file.tgz [Content-Type=application/x-tar]...
  Your credentials are invalid. Please run

  $ gcloud auth login
```

The only way I could get this to work is to **actually** run `gcloud auth login` and allow the authentication in a web browser.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this intended for every service account?

Comment: How have you installed gsutil? As part of GCloud installation or as standalone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here.

**My Solution**

Instead of using `gsutil`, I decided to use the Google Cloud Client Libraries.

What I *did*:

```
gsutil cp my_file.tgz gs://my_bucket
```

What I am doing *now*:

```
from gcloud import storage

# key file is located in my current directory
os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS', 'gcloud-auth.json')

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("my_bucket")
blob = bucket.blob("my_file.tgz")
blob.upload_from_filename("my_file.tgz")
```

**Hindsight 20/20**

After getting the above solution working, it seems if I also set the environment variable, `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, my `gsutil` should've worked too. (untested)